# prisma how to disable not null

Tags: prisma

my model is like this

```js
model Trackings {
    deliverStatus   String   @default("") @db.VarChar(255)
    @@map(name: "trackings")
}
```

run

```
 npx run db push
```

I got this sql

```sql
`deliverStatus ` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
```

The problem is I got `Not Null` in the sql, I didn't mean to do that. How to tell prisma not to do that ?

A side question, I didn't mean to have this one too `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci` but prisma added it anyway, how to stop that?

Answer (score 1):

I just need to do this, add the `?`

```js
model Trackings {
    deliverStatus?   String   @default("") @db.VarChar(255)
    @@map(name: "trackings")
}
```